# How to show two different app usage message for NSCameraUsageDescription

Tags: ios, plist, ios-permissions

In my application, the camera used in two places so how can I show two different messages for "NSCameraUsageDescription".

I've created the strings file to add messages for multiple languages but the message for camera access should not be same.

I couldn't find any document related to showing different messages for camera access on different places.

Answer (score 0):

App usage message is going to shown only once, when you first time use your app. It is not going to be used everytime you use the app. In App, you can use it any number of times at any number of places. You cant show different message for all different places. You have to create single generic message which is just used to take permission from user that we/our app is going to access your private photos as well as your camera. So, message must be to take permission from user.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that message will be shown only once. In my application camera is the main part of the application, we want to provide some more specific message in that area if a user accesses the camera for the first time. Don't want to show same message on other place when user try to access the first time.

Comment: Looks like there is no way for showing two different message. I will make it generic.

Comment: Yes, there is no any other way.. you have to create generic message for both place

Comment: I am also facing this issue, plus the fact that idiot reviewers keep on rejecting the app because the message is..well.. too generic..

Comment: @FabioNapodano : Just reply them in resolution center that - we are using camera at x number of places, the requirement differs at each place. As, we can show only single message for all cases, we have added this generic message to describe it. I think once you reply, they will allow the app.

Comment: @MehulThakkar I tried that. actually, we were in a rush for an urgent update and, after the revirewer didn't reply for two days, we were forced to temporarily disable the features requesting permissions, resubmit the binary, then reenabling them remotely. this is not a correct way to do this kind of things, I know, but when you are not lucky enough to get an understanding and responsive reviewer, there is nothing else you can do other than fool him..

Comment: In the fact that this question has been asked for two years ago from now, is there any solutions came for this? or still this not possible?

Comment: @RoohAl-mahaba : It is still not possible.